# Unity stop add force RigidBody

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to stop the force that is being put on the character. The code is write this way for android.
Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //variables
    public float moveSpeed = 300;
    public GameObject character;

    private Rigidbody2D characterBody;
    private float ScreenWidth;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        ScreenWidth = Screen.width;
        characterBody = character.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int i = 0;
        //loop over every touch found
        while (i < Input.touchCount)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > ScreenWidth / 2)
            {
                //move right
                RunCharacter(1.0f);
            }
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < ScreenWidth / 2)
            {
                //move left
                RunCharacter(-1.0f);
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        RunCharacter(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        #endif
    }

    private void RunCharacter(float horizontalInput)
    {
        //move player
        characterBody.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));

    }
}
```

I have no clue how to stop the force as I am super new and also keep in mind this script is also written so android touch can be used and the script.

Comment: `characterBody.velocity=Vector2.zero;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want the force stopped?

If you want it to stop immediately you can write characterBody.velocity = Vector2.zero as mentioned by Ruzihm in the comments.

If you want the player to gradually slow down to a stop you can add friction to the player, either by physics or in the code by decreasing velocity a certain % in the update loop.

Comment: How would I detect when the touch has been removed. Eg you took off your finger

Comment: @GCIreland https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

Comment: you could use pointer up event using event system